# Checking for Facebook requests in iOS game

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am planning on implementing send gift to Facebook friend via [requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/).

Sending and receiving gift(clicking on the request from the Facebook app) works fine.

But i would like to know is there a way to get the list of all pending requests for the user so i can present them with gift screen without user having to open app throughout Facebook notification.

Similar to this:[image: Pending gifts screen from requests overview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging i found the right Graph API.

To get all pending request you simply use [/me/apprequests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/apprequests/)

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/apprequests"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
                      ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                      }];
```